# Error: A cobalt error was thrown

Tags: error

so I'm working in a large organisation and was wondering what this error meant and if there is a fix to this?

If I go to edit this specific document, even just change the title it comes up with the error 'Error: A Cobalt error was thrown.' (shown in the pic).

Details:
 - we are using office 365 SharePoint
 - this is a .doc file
 - all other .doc files work fine as well as all .docx files.

Tried so far:
 - tried to edit using different users: doesn't matter who is editing the document, error comes up regardless.
 - have tried checking out and checking in, signing out and signing in - does not resolve.
 - have tried to go back to the Classic View and still the error is there.

Currently we have created another .docx file with the same name and uploaded it so we can make changes to that one. But that's really not a solution as in the future we might need to retain the version number so creating a new document and uploading is not ideal.

Not sure what else to try. Any suggestions?

Thanks for all your help.
 [image]